# SELECTED on dynamic select

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic combo box in which data came from the database. its name is 'option_item_class'

[image]
Then when I load my table I just call my combo box in AJAX.

[image]

My question is how can i set default value without using '`<option selected>`'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $('select option[value="1"]').attr("selected",true);

Comment: I cannot insert Jquery into AJAX function.

Comment: By the way thank you, i use alternative way. its fine now

Comment: Try this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEVrVJ

Comment: Okay noted. thanks a lot.